# Where is the correct place to add plugins in my .babelrc file

Tags: node.js, babeljs

This is my file

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
}
```

where should i add { "plugins": ["transform-es3-property-literals"]
      }

Or where do the plugins go?

thanks

This is what I tried

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    }
  }
  {
    "plugins": ["transform-es3-property-literals"]
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation shows you where to put them: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/

Comment: @JoeClay I am doing as I understood it from the docs but my build fails so that is why I was asking. I am adding it in the question now

Comment: What you've posted isn't valid JSON - `plugins` shouldn't be wrapped in curly braces like that. It should be at the top level of the JSON object, like `presets` (or inside a particular env, like your development presets).

Comment: @JoeClay ok, thank you